# Яке походження слова "Карк"?

Tags: етимологія

КАРК (чол.) - задня частина шиї з верхньою частиною хребта, зашийок.
Похідні: КАРКОЛО́МНИЙ, КАРКОЛО́МНІСТЬ.

Таке ж слово можна почути і в польській мові. Але хто в кого його запозичив?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Слово *карк* у так самому сенсі [є](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA#.D0.A0.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9) і в російської мови.

> *Задняя часть шеи с верхней частью позвоночного столба.*

Як ви помітили, таке слово [є](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kark#Polish) і в польскої мови. Тут повідомляється, що:

> *Від прото-слов'янського [*kъrkъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/k%D1%8Ark%D1%8A).*

Схоже, що це слово дійсно має таке походження, бо подібне слово є у багатьох слов'янських мов. У наступному посиланні, в свою чергу, мовляється наступне:

> *З прото-індоєвропейської ***kr̥ko-**.*
>
> Індо-європейське слово має схожість з санскритом **कृकाट** (**kṛkāṭa**), галльською **cricon**. Не дуже переконліві збіги з давньоскандинавською **kverk**, латинською **gurges**, **gurgulío**.

---

Згоден з паном [chizh](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA/1173#1173):

У тому ж посиланні зустрічається таке:

> *[Давньоукраїнська:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_East_Slavic) **коркъ** (korkʺ)
>   
> [Давньопольська:](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#.D0.86.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.96.D1.8F) **kark***

*Додав посилання до назв мов, аби не плутали з [старо-](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).*

Цікаво, що в російській мові теж є корінь *корк*, наприклад [*закорки*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8):

> **Значение** 
>   
> *ед. нет, разг.* заплечье и поясница; место на спине, на котором человек носит, таскает кого-либо ◆ Ну,… вставай, садись на закорки — снесу. *Л. Н. Толстой* ◆ Очень много было провожающих: соседи, друзья, родственники, украинцы и русские, помогали нести вещи, вели больных, а то и несли их на закорках. *А. Кузнецов, «Бабий яр», 1970 г.*
>
> **Синонимы** 
>   
> *устар. (Даль):* закукры, закорточки, забедры, кукорки, закрошни, закрошки

Тут дійсно є питання з **о**/**а**, яким чином відбулась зміна.

Comment: У чеській і словацькій: [Strč prst skrz krk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Str%C4%8D_prst_skrz_krk).

Comment: Що за *мовляється*? Позаяк мою правку цієї відповіді відхилили - чи можу я отримати пояснення для цього слова?

Comment: Для мене така конструкція цілком в новинку, тому не певен що вона правильна (та і звучить дещо кострубато). Але думаю покищо не варто правити. Чи може @bytebuster щось додатково повідомити чи пояснити?

Comment: @BohdanKuts, «для мене така конструкція цілком в новинку» — не дивно, адже навіть «мовляти» (не у значенні вставного слова), на відміну від звичайного «мовити», відмічене в словниках як «заст[аріле]». Не кажучи вже про «[мовлятися](//books.google.com/books?id=yjFtgRDMi2sC&pg=PA472&dq=мовлялося)» (яке настільки рідке, що його навіть немає у словниках). Але будемо вважати це частиною особистого стилю Follower.

Comment: @Sasha, дякую за пояснення :) Але для себе я вже зробив висновок що ukrainian.stackexchange.com більше не про те, як **правильно**, а про те, як **могло б бути** правильно, якби... _і тут цілий список варіацій_. Різні стилі відповідей, відхилення до різних правописів і використання таких архаїчних чи модернових речей, що мені як людині делекій від тих усіх нюансів лігвістики та історії це просто невтямки... і зрештою просто не цікаво. Якось так.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, напрямок задається людьми, що тут вештаються. Надаючи свої відповіді, Ви б могли трішки розбавити оце згадане Вами відхилення у бік «як могло б бути правильно» замість «як правильно». (Фактично, єдина вимога — це щоб відповіді були обґрунтовані і підкріплені джерелами, а не просто «я так вважаю» — та й те є радше забаганкою bytebuster, а не правилом Stack Exchange.) Якщо Ви зникнете, то оце перехилення в певний бік лише збільшиться (адже напрямок спільноти задається сумою напрямків її членів). Але це, звісно, цілковите Ваше право.

Comment: @Sasha, так, я Вас розумію. Але мені нічим оперувати окрім свої здебільшого інтуїтивних знань. А усвідомлюючи що вони запросто можуть бути помилковими та не маючи зацікавлення до української мови в площині лігвістики та наукового вивчення - виходить те що є.
В результаті мені немає чого запропонувати окрім незначних правок. Але якщо і їх відхиляють із "загально-однаковим" поясненням - тоді робити їх теж не має сенсу.
А часу для достеменного дослідження того, що я не використовую - у мене просто не має. Тому, як то кажуть, "сам винен" :)

Comment: @BohdanKuts, ну, оперувати завжди [є чим](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8). Cкажу чесно — я сам аж ніяк не лінгвіст, я подав заявку на Stack Exchange про відкриття цього розділу (ukrainian.stackexchange.com) просто тому, що хотів бачити цей розділ як користувач. Щодо правок, то бачу, що 7 із 9 Ваших правок прийняли (причому інша, [здається](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/428), була відхилена помилково — принаймні, я особисто не бачу причин її відхиляти і особисто голосував за те, щоб її прийняли).

Answer (score 9):

Обидві мови отримали це слово у спадок від праслов'янської.

Прошу звернути увагу на такі відомості: польське [`kark`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kark) походить від праслов'янського [`*kъrkъ`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/k%D1%8Ark%D1%8A), від якого також походить староукраїнське `коркъ`, в той час як старопольська вже мала варіант `kark`.

Справжня проблема полягає у пошуку відомостей, щодо **переходу українських `о` в `а` в подібних ситуаціях**. Ці відомості необхідні для того, щоб з'ясувати чи вплинув польський варіант на український, або ж `коркъ` перейшов у `карк` *питомим* чином.

Answer (score 0):

Офіційно, українське слово карк вважалося запозиченням з польської мови. Російське, очевидно також. Щоправда, там є деяка семантична відмінність його вживання в українській мові на відміну від російської. Адже, переважно як діалектизм, карк вживається, також, у значенні цілої шиї, як і у деяких західних слов'ян.  Це й більше зближує його, зокрема, з чеським словом.
Згідно з "Тлумачним словником польської мови" Александра Брюкнера (Alexander Bruckner "Slownyk etymologycznyi jezyka polskiego"), карк є "прасловом" ( можливо праслов'янським. Вчений також вважав за необхідне порівняти з індійським словом " krkety" - кола шиї.
Також існувало в діалектах української мови слово "ґарґала", яке однак може бути так званим "false cognate" зі словом  "карк" (наприклад через непряму спорідненість) або ж "false friend" (трохи змінене значення - адже означає воно, зокрема, "горло".

Comment: staflon, добрий день. Наскільки я розумію, це мало бути доповнення до якоїсь із відповідей? До якої саме — chizh чи stegetsj? (Можна перетворити це на коментар до відповіді? Або, якщо можна, трішки відредагувати відповідь, щоб було ясно, до чого це доповнення.)