# Як краще перекласти Wow-effect?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Треба визнати, це поширений вираз, який в гуглі дає понад 11 тис. результатів (утім, не всі українською мовою). Якщо не хочеться використовувати кальку **вау-ефект**, то чим можна замінити це словосполучення?

Мої варіанти одним словом:

- здивування;
- захоплення;
- шок;
- несподіванка.

Але такі переклади недоречні в багатьох випадках. Мене особливо цікавить переклад **wow-effect** в контексті негативного забарвлення або іронії. Приклади взяла з інтернету:

> Все це радше вау-ефект, елемент шоу, комерційний продукт, створений
> талановитими майстрами.
>
> Дуже важливий вау-ефект. Хороша презентація, обіцянки вирішення
> складних проблем і... головне - надприбутки.
>
> Цей фінт виглядає дуже ефектно, проте в сучасному футболі принесе
> скоріше вау-ефект, ніж реальну користь.

Через рос. сервіс [Мультитран](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?t=4893616_2_1&s1=WOW%20effect) знайшла переклад **сногсшибательный эффект**, що далі українською перекладається як **карколомний ефект**. Результатом незадоволена. Хотілося б знайти сталий вираз, метафору чи щось таке метке й українське.

Comment: А чим са́ме незадоволені? *Карк* — цілком собі древнє слово, [прийшло](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1172/) до нас ще з тих часів, як протоукраїнці :) говорили санскритом: कृकाट `/kṛkāṭa/`. Особисто мені не подобається лише голосна /о/, мало б бути *-ламний*.

Comment: @bytebuster вау далеко не карколамне, не задоволена тим, що вийде, коли в наведені приклади поставити карколамний ефект. Проти древнього слова нічого не маю.

Comment: З [коментаря](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/2471974362928595?comment_id=2472638346195530) у фейсбуці: «В карпатських говірках найкращий відповідник —„йой“».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пошук словосполучення "вау-ефект" показує велику кількість статей про рекламування своїх товарів або послуг. Одною з провідних компаній, що зробила ідею "вау-ефекту" головною у презентації та продажу своєї продукції називають компанію Apple, що намагається використовувати його у кожному елементі - коробка, пристрій, програмне забезпечення, - все повинно викликати у покупця захоплення.

Засновник компанії - Стів Джобс,- казав що кнопки програм мають бути такими щоб їх хотілося облизати (точніше "We made the buttons on the screen look so good you'll want to lick them").

Тобто "вау-ефект" це рекламна стратегія, метою якої є створення у глядача бажання володіти цим товаром (або мати такий стиль життя, вміти зробити такий трюк).

На мою думку можна використати зв'язок із рекламою і перекласти "wow-effect" в негативно-іронічному сенсі як:

- рекламний ефект;
- рекламний трюк;
- видовищний трюк;
- видовищний ефект.

Наприклад:

> Все це радше **рекламний трюк**, елемент шоу, комерційний продукт, створений талановитими майстрами.
>
> Дуже важливий **рекламний ефект**. Хороша презентація, обіцянки вирішення складних проблем і... головне - надприбутки.
>
> Цей фінт виглядає дуже ефектно, проте в сучасному футболі це скоріше **видовищний трюк**, ніж практичний прийом.

Comment: саме такої відповіді я й потребувала)

Comment: Для мене wow effect більше пов'язаний з електронікою, аніж з рекламою. І в моїх результатах ґуґла купа схем на це словосполучення.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Наведіть будь-ласка приклади. У відповіді зазначено, що Apple активно використовує wow-ефект, тому не дивно що електроніка і вау-ефект пов'язані. Але фраза "вау-ефект більше пов'язаний з електронікою, а не з рекламою", як на мене, може означати що це якийсь інженерний термін з галузі електроніки, а не такий, що стосується реклами. Наприклад "Бутси пов'язані з футболом, а не з рекламою".

Comment: Спробуйте набрати "вау ефект схема гітара" в анонімному режимі.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko - я вас зрозумів, але це "омонім" з іншої сфери. Мається на увазі ефект який додається до електрогітари на кшталт такого: https://youtu.be/-RK3ifz9lUc?t=37 Це, очевидно, не те що шукає автор питання.

Answer (score 6):

1. [**Ух ти!**](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukh) —  уживається при вираженні здивування, захоплення і т. ін.
   Пропонується вживати, наприклад, у сполученні виду *ефект "ух ти!"*
2. [**Нічого собі!**](http://sum.in.ua/s/nichogho) — (розмовне) Непогано.
3. [**Фурор**](http://sum.in.ua/s/furor). *Зробити фурор* — сильно вразити своїм надзвичайним виглядом, манерами, поведінкою і т. ін.
4. [**Вражаючий**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vrazhaty) («який?»), [**вражаюче**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vrazhajuche) («як?») — Викликати почуття подиву, захоплення тощо; дивувати.
   *Вражати око (очі)* — дивувати незвичайним виглядом, ситуацією.
5. **Створювати {лише} {яскраве} враження**

Отже,

> Все це радше **вражаючий око** ефект, елемент шоу, комерційний продукт, створений талановитими майстрами.
>
> Дуже важливий **ефект «ух ти!»**. Хороша презентація, обіцянки вирішення складних проблем і... головне - надприбутки.
>
> Цей фінт виглядає дуже ефектно, проте в сучасному футболі скоріше **зробить лише фурор**, ніж {принесе} реальну користь.
>
> So each year it's been an escalating contest to see who can give the gift with the most wow factor — Отже, кожне Різдво перетворюється на все більш масове змагання з того, хто з нас зробить найбільш **вражаючий** подарунок.

Answer (score 4):

я'б дослівно, а тобто "ого-ефект"

Багато перекладачів його не перекладають, тобто "вов-кають". На практиці коли я перекладаю то використовую слово "ого". Воно зазвичай виражає приємне здивування, але не завжди.

Comment: Добрий день. Ця відповідь не підкріплена джерелами й прикладами застосування такого перекладу. Можна очікувати досить багато мінусів. На SE такі відповіді не заохочуються.

Comment: Хоч я й плюсанув відповідь, та все ж згоден із зауваженням.

Comment: "Можна очікувати досить багато мінусів." бажання людини бути соціальною за рахунок схвалення у вигляді так званих плюсів це таке собі. Стислість, власна думка та інтуїтивність лиш це я маю.

Comment: З іншого боку, [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5136/240) ви не полінувались дати посилання на словники)

Comment: Якщо ви не збираєтесь додавати якісь джерела й пояснення - я перетворюю цей пост на коментар.

Comment: Ну, начебто я додав значення вигуку.

Comment: Не завжди просто носіям мови пояснити складно прості речі. В цьому допомагають додаткові запитання, які вказують на частини речення, які не зрозумів читач.

Comment: або ще більше посилення - огого-ефект )

Answer (score 3):

**[Вплив](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2) "[ОГО](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)!"** - [wow](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wow) [effect](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/effect)

**1. Англійський варіант**

> **Effect**
>   The effect of one thing on another is the change that the first thing
>   causes in the second thing.
>
> **WOW**
>   You can say 'wow' when you are very impressed, surprised, or pleased.

**2. Український варіант**

> **ВПЛИВ** Дія, яку певна особа чи предмет або явище виявляє стосовно іншої
>   особи чи предмета.
>
> **ОГО́** Уживається для вираження здивування, захоплення, застереження і
>   т. ін. з приводу чогось надзвичайного, несподіваного, непередбаченого
>   і т. ін.

**3. Переклад прикладів**

> Все це радше вау-ефект, елемент шоу, комерційний продукт, створений талановитими майстрами.

Все це радше "**ОГО!**", частина показу, комерційний виріб, створений талановитими майстрами.

> Дуже важливий вау-ефект. Хороша презентація, обіцянки вирішення складних проблем і... головне - надприбутки.

Дуже важливе "**ОГО!**". Хороший показ, обіцянки вирішення складних проблем і... головне -  надприбутки.

> Цей фінт виглядає дуже ефектно, проте в сучасному футболі принесе скоріше вау-ефект, ніж реальну користь.

Це вдавання виглядає дуже впливово, проте в сучасній грі "підніжний м'яч" вплине скоріше як "**ОГО!**", ніж принесе справжню користь.

*Якщо прочитати мій варіант, то зрозуміють усі. Якщо ж прочитати ваш варіант, то більша частина людей, що не знайома з англійською чи французькою культурою вимагатиме пояснень.*

Comment: Я в сказав, що _вплив_ — це радше _influence_; а _effect_ хоча й має доволі широкий спектр значень, але в цьому контексті я б усе-таки перекладав його як _ефект_. Тобто все-таки _[ефект «ОГО!»](/a/5164)_, а не _вплив «ОГО!»_. А просто одне слово «ОГО!» стане загальнозрозумілим у ролі назви явища лише тоді, як стане загальновідомим словосполучення _ефект/вплив «ОГО!»_ (тоді люди почнуть його скорочувати, але не раніше). Але це лише моя думка, можливо я неправий. У будь-якому разі мені подобається ця відповідь (хоч я й частково незгоден).

Comment: З точки зору словника - це слова синоніми. З моєї точки зору, і якщо почитати переклад та етимологію, та й за значенням в даному випадку, то стає зрозумілим, що можна використовувати слово вплив. Немає доводів проти використання слова вплив у значенні перекладу слова effect з англійської.

Comment: influence - це сила впливу, властивість впливати, а не сам вплив.

Comment: Може тоді вже ого-враження або ого-ефект. Слово ефект є в словнику.

Answer (score 2):

Як щодо ах? Ах-ефект асоціюється в мене з чимось ах яким чудовим.

"Овва" було б непоганим еквівалентом, якби так люди в наш час висловлювалися.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: І так справді кажуть. Наприклад: [«Перша археологічна виставка Вікентія Хвойки створила в ті дні, як то кажуть, „ах-ефект“»](https://www.facebook.com/livingcitykyiv/posts/366133917415829/), [«В Обирку я відчула такий „ах-ефект“, коли вперше стала на ходулі»](http://astudia.kubg.edu.ua/pro-nas/podii/260-diana-karpenko-zelene-plem-ya-tse-shkola-mystetstv-i-remesel.html), [«Якогось „ах-ефекту“ для шкіри від неї не очікувала (а його і не обіцяють), функцію очищення без подразнення вона виконує і добре»](http://posydenky.lvivport.com/threads/kosmetika-xto-jaku.26657/page-97#post-646369).

Comment: @Sasha маємо проблему: видалена відповідь нижче і ця відповідь, хоч і не аналоґічні за наповненням, але дуже близькі, але нижчу відповідь ви перевели в коментар, а цю - ні. Що скажете?

Comment: @P.Vowk, ну, (1) цю відповідь я спробував врятувати, додавши приклади використання в коментарях (хоча, звісно, краще, щоб вони були в самій відповіді), а та прикладів використання не має (і я навіть не можу їх знайти); (2) та за формулюванням справді більше виглядає як відповідь на відповідь (тобто вона продовжує думку однієї з відповідей про «ого-ефект»). Але якщо Ви про справедливість, то вийшло справді не дуже справедливо.