# Вилка чи виделка?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, росіянізм

На сайті [Онлайнкоректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0/) знайшов інформацію, що не можна вживати слово "вилка" у значенні "знаряддя для їди, що має форму ручки з кількома зубцями", а замість нього вживати слово "виделка", але якщо ми [заглянемо у СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9421&page=329), то побачимо, що там ці два слова є синонімами. Та й на сайті Вікіпедії пише, що можна вживати обидва слова, однак, таки зазначається, що рідше вживається слово "вилка".

Отож, чи буде правильним вживанням як одного так і іншого слова у значенні "знаряддя для їди" (багато людей можуть сказати, що слово "вилка" має російське походження, однак така ж сама ситуація і зі словом "виделка" - воно походить від widelec і по суті утворилося від поєднання цього слова із, на диво, словом "вилка" (згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)) )?

Comment: Слово ВИЛКА можна вживати і вас зрозуміють. Але в українській мові існує більш автентичне слово на позначення виключно знаряддя для їжі - ВИДЕЛКА. Див. пов'язане запитання за посиланням: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/

Comment: СУМ-20 — академічне джерело, укладене і перевірене професіоналами. Онлайнкоректор — просто сайт, джерела якого невідомі. Я занадто часто бачив всякі дурниці, які потужно педалюються різними сайтами/блогами, але нормальними джерелами не підтверджуються.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Беручи до уваги інформацію від шановного викладача (Охорони праці), яку я запам'ятав на все життя:

[Вилка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9421&page=329) — це технічне, та буде помилкою використання слова "виделка"

> техн. Деталь механізму, приладу, яка має роздвоєний кінець. Проскуров
>   похитав головою і вийняв вилку штепселя (Іван Ле, Право.., 1957, 167).

[Виделка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8565&page=308) — столовий предмет, також в побуті зустрічається як "вилка"

> предмет столового прибору у вигляді ручки з кількома зубцями, яким
>   беруть і кладуть до рота шматки їжі.

Answer (score 2):

Визначення взяти з СУМ-20

> **[ВИДЕ́ЛКА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8565&page=308)**, и, ж. Предмет столового прибору у вигляді ручки з кількома зубцями, яким беруть і кладуть до рота шматки їжі. *Усе
>   срібне-золоте, усе срібне-золоте! І ложки, і тарілки, і ножі, і
>   виделки* (Г. Квітка-Основ'яненко).
>
> **[ВИ́ЛКА1](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9421&page=329)**, и, ж. 1. рідко. Те саме, що виде́лка. *Тарілки, ножі й вилки загарчали, як собаки, аж підскочили* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *В
>   салоні пані Олімпії говір, брязкіт вилок та ножів об тарілки* (І.
>   Франко).

[З словника синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> **ВИДЕ́ЛКА** (знаряддя для їди, що має форму ручки з кількома зубцями), **ВИДЕ́ЛЬЦЕ** рідше, **ВИ́ЛКА** розм. рідко.

Отже, обидва слова можна вживати в значені "знаряддя для їди".

Comment: Але «вилка» — **рідко**. Притому в СУМ-11 (на відміну від СУМ-20) «[вилка](http://sum.in.ua/s/vylka)» ще не було рідко.

Comment: Таки варто звернути увагу на оце "рідко" в СУМ-20. Можемо бачити перехід до нової традиції й відхід від синонімів, що більше нагадують російський варіант.

Answer (score 1):

These words are regional. My family is from the Lviv region that now exists in Ukraine as well as the Lemko region, a Ukrainian area that exists in the country of Poland. About 60+ years ago I learned the word for fork as *виделец*, which is the same as in Polish. Sometimes we heard the word *виделка* as well, which was used by the post-WW2 emigre community from western Ukraine. The further east one went, the more likely the word *вилка* was used. It is also the word used in Russian.

---

<sup>*Чужий вільний переклад.*</sup>

Ці слова регіональні. Моя родина походить зі Львівської області, території у складі України, а також з Лемківщини, що є українською етнічною територією, яка зараз належить до Польщі. Близько 60 років тому я вивчив слово *виделец*, що звучить так само і польською. Інколи ми чули й слово *виделка*, яке вживала післявоєнна емігрантська спільнота із Західної України. Чимдалі на Схід, тим частіше вживане слово *вилка*, котре, у свою чергу, звучить так, як і московською.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for joining Ukrainian.SE. This site is a bilingual one, and we equally [appreciate](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/) questions asked in Ukrainian or English (or both). However, when **answering**, it is best to answer in language of original question (optionally, adding translation). Yet another problem is that **answers based solely on personal experience** do not work well unless they are backed with some solid references or academic research. You can [edit] your answer at any time by clicking the link under the post.

Answer (score 1):

З огляду на походження, можна чітко ствердити, що вилка — питомо українське слово.

[Збереження праслов'янського суфікса *dl (*dьl): вагадло, виделка,
ковадло, повидло, простирадло, чуперадло (пор. пол. mydło, szydło,
widły, що відповідають українським мило, шило, вила)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC#%D0%92_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

Але сьогочасні мовознавці чомусь розрізняють значення буцімто воно стосується винятково технічної царини.