# Як перевірити правильність написання слова "виделка"?

Tags: правопис

За яким правилом треба писати слово "виделка" саме через "И", а не "Е" чи "I"? Або яким словом можна перевірити першу голосну літеру?

Особисто мені одразу спадає на згадку ["Кум виделкою, я ложкою — їмо."](https://poems.net.ua/poet/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87/%D0%AF%D0%BA_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BC_%D0%86_%D0%AF)
Саме такий правопис запропонований і в СУМ-20 ([за лінком у треді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)), але помилку можна знайти у словниках гугл-перекладача:
[image: wrong translate fork]
Я вже повідомляв про це до підтримки Google Translate, але безрезультатно. Можу звернутися також через спеціалізований форум, але в цьому випадку краще мати сильне підгрунтя, кваліфікована відповідь на StackExchange буде для Google авторитетною. То ж, допоможіть будь ласочка. Бо проблема вже набрала масовий характер - на запит "веделка" (саме у лапках для точного входження) пошукова система Google індексує 17400 документів з помилкою.
[image]

Comment: На запитання «як перевірити правильність…?» або «За яким правилом треба писати…?» відповідь у словниках і у запитанні, посилання на яке ви самі надали: *«в**е**делка»* не є словниковим словом. Якщо ж запитання про те, що онлайн-словник Google Translate містить помилку, то мені здається, що відповідь не до нас; Google Translate має community-driven засоби до редагування, і нічого більшого ми відповісти не можемо.

Comment: Мені «Гугл» дає трішки іншу статистику: ["виделка"](https://www.google.com/search?q="виделка") — 131000, ["веделка"](https://www.google.com/search?q="веделка") — 96.

Comment: @Sasha, саме так, якщо ви "у логіні" в аккаунт, буде сформовано індивідуальну видачу з урахуванням хісторі, вподобань та інших налаштувань акаунта, я бачу "веделка" — 99. Але в загальному пошуку (нова вкладка в режимі "інкогніто"), сьогодні бачу "веделка" - 17000, "виделка" - 117 000.

Comment: @RomanMikhol, і справді…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах, том 1, с. 370](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=370) каже:

> **виде́лка**, [*віде́лка* Я, *виде́лиц* МСБГ, *виде́лци* МСБГ];— р. [*виде́лка*], бр. *відэ́лец*, *відэ́лка*; — запозичення з польської мови; п. widelec, widelca «виделка» походить від widly «вила», спорідненого з укр. *ви́ла*; k виникло на місці п. c внаслідок зближення з укр. *ви́лка*.— ЭСБМ II 130.— Див. ще **ви́ла**.
>
> <sub>Позначення:
>
>   • […] — діалект.
>
>   • Я. — *Яворницький Д. І.* Словник української мови. Т. 1. Катеринослав, 1920.
>
>   • МСБГ. — *Матеріали* до словника буковинських говірок. Вип. 1—6 (А—О). Чернівці, 1971—1979.
>
>   • р. — російська.
>
>   • бр. — білоруська.
>
>   • п. — польська.
>
>   • «…» — значення.
>
>   • ЭСБМ — *Этымалагічны* слоўник беларускай мовы. Т. 1—2, А—В. Мінск, 1978—1980. Автори: Р. У. Краўчук, В. У. Мартынаў, А. Я. Супрун та ін. Редактор В. У. Мартынаў.</sub>

Тобто за походженням мало б бути *и* або *і*.

Але [bytebuster](/u/8) правильно в [коментарі](/q/6130#comment10148_6130) пише, що першочергову роль має сучасний ужиток, а не походження. Тож Вам варто посилатися на звичайні словники: [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/vydelka), [СУМ-20](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8565&page=308), [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), словники на [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) і [E2U](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), інші. Або на частоти вживання в літературі (наскільки я розумію, це те, на основі чого формуються словники літературної мови): [2340 виделок](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=cqlrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql="%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA.*"&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.publicationCity=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=) проти [3 «веделок»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=cqlrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql="%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA.*"&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.publicationCity=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=).

Comment: @Sasha Хіба СУМ-11 не вважається морально застарілим? Інші словники, які ви навели, виглядають теж досить старими...

Comment: @improbable, «Словники України on-line» від УМІФ — 2008, 2-й том СУМ-20 — 2012. А які новіші Ви знаєте?

Comment: Добре, [«Новий українсько-англійський словник» (Є. І. Гороть, С. В. Гончарук, Л. К. Малімон, О. О. Рогач) 2016 року](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=виделка&dicts=18). Загалом, я не думаю, що написання цього слова може легко змінитися.

Comment: Не уточнив, конкретно мав на увазі [цей](https://r2u.org.ua/main/dicts) із списку і E2U також має серед джерел досить старий словник.

Comment: і справді, спочатку почулося саме "і" - в"і"делка і лише щоб записати спала на думку фраза для перевірки. А щодо сучасного вжитку, ВИЛКОЮ ми користуємость в побуті, ВИДЕЛКОЮ лише у віршах.